# How to do logging throughout the application?

Tags: java, logging, javafx, slf4j

I have a JavaFX application that has buttons for connecting via JMS. I want to have a connection log reading messages and other JMS functions in a TextArea. That is, the application started and the start log was added to the TextField. There was an error, then it was also displayed in the TextArea

Sample code for connecting to a broker:

```
public static void connectBrokerSend(String urlBroker) {
        QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
        QueueConnection connection;
        QueueSession queueSession = null;
            connectionFactory = new ActiveMQQueueConnectionFactory("tcp://" + urlBroker);
            connection = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
            queueSession = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
 }
```

Code of the TextArea itself:

```
<TextArea layoutX="20.0" layoutY="755.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="560.0" fx:id=""LOG/>
```

Comment: what have you tried? libraries like log4j are somewhat common, give that a look.

Comment: was this an error from pasting here `fx:id=""LOG` ?